# Can not Navigate to Master Detail Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

i have axamarin app with login page that leads to modules launcher landing page 
one of those modules is a master  details page

every thing is working fine from VS (debug / release) ether emulator or real device

however out of VS, from emulator or device itself if i run the app everything work fine except the navigation to master detail page (without any response)

i tried to navigate to a detailed page directly (without the master page) it works
i tried to put a "/" at the start  or remove it , i tried "/NavigationPage" or without it

still not working from the app outside VS.

i did the latest update (7.2.0.1422)

here is my xml codes :

1. navigation button from landing page

   ```
           <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" 
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        HeightRequest="80"
                        BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                        Source="homescreenbtn12.png"
                        Command="{Binding NavigationCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="NavigationPage/MwaslaMasterDetailPage"
                        IsVisible="{Binding CurrentUser.IsTPEmplyess}"/>
   ```

2.master details page it self

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
              prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
              x:Class="TPS.Modules.Mwasla.Views.MwaslaMasterDetailPage"
              xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TPS.Modules.Mwasla.Views;assembly=TPS.Modules.Mwasla">

<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MwaslaMasterPageMenu/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>

        <x:Arguments>
            <views:MwaslaContactUsPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

3. the normally navigation command 
      async void ExecuteCommandName(string parameter)
           {
               await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(parameter);
           }

kindly help

Comment: It is not a good design to Navigate from a ContentPage to Master Detail Page . It would be better to set the `MainPage`  in the NavigationCommand . `Application.Current.MainPage = new MwaslaMasterDetailPage();`

Comment: that is the documentation of Prism for Xamarin forms , and it runes from vs 2019 , but not on stand alone ????

Comment: Check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65852/prism-and-navigationpage .

Comment: i did used your approach  Application.Current.MainPage = new MwaslaMasterDetailPage(); and i got the same behavior every thing is working fine if the app is running from VS , but if it is running as stand alone app , it does not navigate at all? and if the page is not the master-detailed page ( any contained page) it works ?????

Comment: You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: how to do that ? i can give you access to git repository need your account for that

Comment: You could upload it to github . Don't forget to remove your personal information .

Comment: it is on git hub , just i will remove the personal data, after that how to share it with you , i need your account name on git hub to do that

Comment: You just need to share the link .

Comment: here u r https://github.com/amr-alaa/TPSociety

Comment: @Amr.Alaa the link seems to direct to a private or non-existent repo....

Comment: @dansiegel i added you to the project and i do use prism since V 4 and now for both WPF and Xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues I want to address here...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
              prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
              x:Class="TPS.Modules.Mwasla.Views.MwaslaMasterDetailPage"
              xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TPS.Modules.Mwasla.Views;assembly=TPS.Modules.Mwasla">

<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MwaslaMasterPageMenu/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:MwaslaContactUsPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

### Core Concepts

In this sample there are essentially 3 pages that need to be understood...

- The Master Page (MwaslaMasterPageMenu)... it's fine if you want to separate the View for the Master into another XAML page but remember that this should NOT have it's own ViewModel nor should you attempt to set AutowireViewModel on that page.
- The MasterDetailPage... this is the actual root navigation context that you are navigating from. This is the page that requires the ViewModel which you have explicitly set AutowireViewModel on
- The Detail Page (MwaslaContactUsPage in a NavigationPage)... while this is technically correct for a Xamarin.Forms app and would allow you navigate to `/MwaslaMasterDetailPage`, it's not recommended that you do this. You should instead be explicit in setting the Detail `/MwaslaMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/MwaslaContactUsPage`

### Issues with Navigation

Navigation in Prism.Forms is based on the Page which you want to Navigate from in context. This is why in the past there requirements that the Navigation service was a named parameter. Before Prism resolves the ViewModel, it first constructs a new instance of the NavigationService and provides it the navigation context (the Xamarin.Forms.Page aka the View) that the ViewModel will be attached to.

### Fixes

- First you'll want to move all of the logic from the MwaslaMasterPageMenuViewModel and move it to the MwaslaMasterDetailPageViewModel
- Get rid of the MwaslaMasterPageMenuViewModel and remove the AutowireProperty from the MwaslaMasterPageMenu.xaml
- Remember that a MasterDetailPage is meant to be the NavigationRoot. This means that if you look at the MasterDetailPage's Parent, it should be your App.
- Remember that in order to get the classic "Hamburger" look that people typically want with the MasterDetailPage your Detail needs to be a NavigationPage. In order to achieve this correctly you should refrain from explicitly setting the Detail Page so that you properly navigate to any detail page within the MasterDetailPage, ie `/MyMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/ViewA`
- When considering the previous comment remove references like `/MyMasterDetailPage` or `/NavigationPage/MyMasterDetailPage`

### Navigating from the Master aka "Menu"

Remember that when you're navigating from the Master Page aka the Menu, you're navigating not from the Master Page at all but from the MasterDetailPage. As such you will simply do a relative navigation like `NavigationPage/ViewA` or `NavigationPage/ViewB` for anything that will change out the Detail Page.

Comment: thanks a lot dear for the detailed reply , i will follow exactly your steps and revert back to you, but i have a big question mark , why does every thing run correctly from Visual Studio , if the logic is not correct it should not run at all.

Comment: i want to mention that the Master detail page is the root of the module , not the App as per customer request, also in the navigation for the module home page i added "/" at the binning , to set the root navigation to the <aster details page.

Comment: note that anytime your navigation uri starts with `/` you are resetting the NavigationStack... in essence it is equivalent to `app.MainPage = new SomeOtherPage()`. I'm also not sure what you mean by it runs from Visual Studio.

Comment: when i press F5 from VS and it deploy the app into a real device or the emulator the navigation to Master  Details page work fine in debug and releade mode

Answer (score 0):

finally it works

thanks Dan Siegel for detailed answer

It Work like Magic